# How to restore configuration xml from IIS 7 to IIS 10 (Windows 2016)

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-7, restore, iis-10

In IIS 7.0 I used 'Export configuration' to generate the xml files.
When trying o import it/restore it in IIS 10.0, it says OK.
I close and open IIS and everything is gone (features on the right pane, etc).
I tried to make sure that all modules used in IIS 7 were installed on 10.0 (i.e: URLRewrite).

No luck - did it twice; after each import, I had to uninstall and re-install IIS roles & features on the server.

If anybody can help, I would highly appreciate it!

Thanks!